# Convert "$.each(data, function (index)" to coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, coffeescript

I'm having trouble transforming this from Jquery/Javascript to coffeescript, simply because I am a beginner and I'm finding it hard to grasp. Could someone give me a hand?

```
    $.each(data, function (index) {
        arrayOfThings.push(data[index].thing);
    });
```

This is within a function that takes in AJAX 'GET' data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are cleaner ways to do that loop using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). `$.each` passes the callback function the index *and* the element so you could say:

```
$.each data, (index, e) ->
    arrayOfThings.push(e.thing)
```

`$.each` also sets `this` (AKA `@` in CoffeeScript) to the current element so you can also say:

```
$.each data, -> arrayOfThings.push(@thing)
```

and ignore the callback arguments altogether.

Since your `$.each` is effectively unwrapping an array, you could use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) instead of `$.each` to simplify the callback:

```
arrayOfThings = $.map data, (e) -> e.thing
```

CoffeeScript functions have an implicit return so `-> x` is the same as `-> return x`, this is handy for small mapping functions like this.

If you can assume a reasonably sensible JavaScript environment, then you could use the native [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of jQuery's version:

```
arrayOfThings = data.map (e) -> e.thing
```

Loops in CoffeeScript are expressions that yield arrays (see [**Loops and Comprehensions**](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) in the docs for details). That means that you can skip `$.each` completely and use a `for ... in` loop:

```
a = (e.thing for e in data)
```

That assumes that `data` is an array. If `data` is an object with object values then you could use a `for ... of` loop:

```
a = (v.thing for k, v of data)
```

And if you already have an array and want add new things to it, you could use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
a = a.concat(e.thing for e in data)
```

or use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and a [CoffeeScript splat](http://coffeescript.org/#splats):

```
a.push((e.thing for e in data)...)
```

You can combine these last two (i.e. `concat` and splat/`push`) with the `$.map` and `Array.prototype.map` versions as well.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Jq6Mh/2/

Comment: I've already upvoted this, but if you add a map example, it will be more complete.

Comment: @JoeHildebrand: Fair enough, no need to stop short. I tossed in `$.map` and `Array::map` versions too.

Comment: Nice.  Anything worth doing is worth overdoing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do (though there are some choices you can make as far as brackets and such go.

```
$.each data, (index) ->
    arrayOfThings.push(data[index].thing)
```

The biggest difference is the lack of javascript's `function(){}` syntax, instead using coffeescript's `() ->` syntax.  Also some brackets can be removed (optional) and of course, the semicolons.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't quite see how function(){} directly translated to ()->.

Comment: since the result is pushed to an array, you might as well use $.map